# Finding two numbers in a string lua

Tags: lua, numbers, detection

I wish for some way to isolate the numbers 98 and 7,525.07 in the following string using lua.

"I can confirm todays incident total file has been uploaded.   There are 98 incidents totalling  7,525.07"

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I have this which picks up the first number, but I'm struggling on picking up the second figure

```
number = string.match(
    "I can confirm todays incident total file has been uploaded.   There are 98 incidents totalling  7,525.07",
    "%d+"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if first value only numeric chars you can use this match:

```
local s = "I can confirm todays incident total file has been uploaded. There are 98 incidents totalling 7,525.07"
print (s:match(".-(%d+).-([%d%.%,]+)") )
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great.  Would you mind explaining the code following s:match? Isolating the final figure of 7,525.07 would be useful.

Comment: last figure: `local x = s:match(".-%d+.-([%d%.%,]+)")`  or  `x = s:match("(%d+%,?%d+%.?%d+)")`

Comment: Fantastic.  Is it possible to drop the comma but keep the decimal point?

Comment: you can drop the comma before match: `print ( s:gsub(",",""):match("(%d-%.%d+)") )` it's shorter